# remove protruding brick on LR chimney

Tags: brick, cutting

In our living room over the firebox we would like to hand a flat screen TV.  The design of the brick is a Running or Stretcher bond but it has 4 brick protruding from it.  Specifically About one third of the way above the fire box on the outside wall there is 
Centered on one side two brick with their "header edges" protruding, half a brick width from the wall and then another one third up the wall, centered on the other side there is the same.  My question is how to best remove the parts of these four brick protruding and flatten the wall ?  home built in late 1970's

Comment: Pictures would help in this regard. although what you describe is quite sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

I would not break or cut the bricks, someday you (or someone else) may want to move the TV and have a wall that is still aesthetically pleasing. Cut or chiseled bricks just won't look right.

Use wood (or some other material) blocks to "fur" the wall out. In other words, mount the TV off of the wall the same distance that the bricks protrude.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve your problem is to break the bricks off (ie in half). The problem there is that you want to ensure you get a nice, clean cut.

You will Need a brick chisel, grinder, diamond blade and a hammer.

Step1. Cut 3 Relief cuts on each brick. Three cuts because you will not cut a relief cut on the surface which you will be chiselling. (I would apply the chisel on one of the long brick face surfaces. Try to get the relief cuts flush with the wall, and make sure they all line up.
Step 2: get your chisel and place it on the face of the brick with no relief cut and Knock hard with hammer. you should get a clean break
Step 3: use the diamond blade and the grinder to "clean" any edges away from the brick by lightly grinding any irregular spots.

[image]